# Angular way of "global controller" for Ionic apps

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, global, controllers

I'm new to ionic and have been wondering the "angular" way of a "global controller".

In my app, I am using the starter tabs template and I want to have a bar with which I want to interact with as the user lays around in my app. And this bar would be placed in my `index.html` like the following.

`index.html`

```
<ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>

<div id="my-player" class="idle">
  <round-progress background-image="{{roundBg}}" background-repeat="no-repeat" background-position="center" background-size="contain" radius="23" stroke="5"></round-progress>
</div>
```

I want this `div#my-player` to be modified as the user plays around with the app.

The initial state for `#my-player` would be hidden, which I would do so via the css class `.idle`. But when the user get to my `/#/tabs/replay/{:id}` page and clicks on an item, I want to add a `angularAudioObject` and display the audio information in `#my-player`.

I found it very inefficient to repeat the same code over and over again all of my controllers so I wondered if there was a way to keep this audio-controlling code could be written once and not be called upon in all of my controllers.

P.S. Yes and I'm aware of services and how they could be included in my controllers but I was wondering if there is a way to keep this code "seemingly be integrated onto" my `index.html` file.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't really matter which file has the code in it just that the file is loaded and executed.  That said you should use services or factories to define objects that you want to persist for the life of the application and for any code that would otherwise be repeated (assuming it isn't something that makes more sense as a filter or directive).

Controllers are ephemeral they are created and destroyed as you navigate views.  You can have a controller outside the ui-views that could be a parent of all the other controllers but it's really a fragile way to build things.  Instead take advantage of the simple DI.